# Can connect to docker container via bridge IP but not 0.0.0.0 inside pod container

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm running Jenkins which runs a container in a pod which runs a maven build.

In the build, a test spins up a [`mysql`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/5.7.31/images/sha256-a175aaebe819a4f0beb626ae99ff771ab885a44f2ba9c104a58ff6665d73e33f?context=explore) container and gets a 'connection refused'. Locally, outside of Jenkins, it works fine.

The container is run via:

```sh
docker run --name mysql_unit_test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abcd1234! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -p 4306:3306 -d mysql:5.7.13
```

`docker ps` produces:

```sh
816a19116f2d  mysql:5.7.13  "docker-entrypoint.s…"  17 hours ago  Up 17 hours  0.0.0.0:4306->3306/tcp  mysql_unit_test
```

And `docker inspect`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "816a19116f2dd947013baa2abe5555317afec448fa8f56258fce4dce53f33a09",
        "Created": "2020-07-22T04:43:36.556743179Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 84461,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-07-22T04:43:37.219671572Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:1195b21c3a45d9bf93aae497f2538f89a09aaded18d6648753aa3ce76670f41d",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/816a19116f2dd947013baa2abe5555317afec448fa8f56258fce4dce53f33a09/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/816a19116f2dd947013baa2abe5555317afec448fa8f56258fce4dce53f33a09/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/816a19116f2dd947013baa2abe5555317afec448fa8f56258fce4dce53f33a09/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/816a19116f2dd947013baa2abe5555317afec448fa8f56258fce4dce53f33a09/816a19116f2dd947013baa2abe5555317afec448fa8f56258fce4dce53f33a09-json.log",
        "Name": "/mysql_unit_test",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {
                    "max-file": "5",
                    "max-size": "50m"
                }
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "4306"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ccba4cc84fd186833c2bb0a6976a356bf1167cc834b06f4165984367b8ca69ef-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf95f3dcd155ff4d3723bb3283e50af755a9a48c1febef3b1889ace131b9242d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/58a035059ace166a43c538e8bd48d80ad80af4bf5c43a3ff1da6b31490fd6380/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/045b842ce5119b1ec1aa1da2e93a54d69df9d16cdbc531746089a4e881bff44a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ed9de3c8ec5891ee8619e4cca70ea041b112650b3fce543840e25ce5acf038f7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf3af22c1d68cd4b42f97896d5b55f9433972354f67b48499fce6fd7a9c8b2da/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/079d799ee0d806d8428533c7ca65347bc579d795e47b5fb8d9f0491d11658261/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ba3cd6723b68d9cde09712cad0dd6f6a3cd3989e5f69872a35d60ea5ab76a12d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0c9c8a78c4f329888e1fb40aba0fc688f1090c84a6823aa443d08445f2c9ba5f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/12cac8cdd33fabd38487d14a1599516f14bd79421f5a9a04cf926ca8d2c5bc0f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f844165a3a8f81c0d5703f0e27b6cb3ace6c6559b256f1b4dcf91158e0f5a384/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/34c41e90c5210a0aec026543d85d5c17e01287a087607b79c74db82ebff94ee5/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ccba4cc84fd186833c2bb0a6976a356bf1167cc834b06f4165984367b8ca69ef/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ccba4cc84fd186833c2bb0a6976a356bf1167cc834b06f4165984367b8ca69ef/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ccba4cc84fd186833c2bb0a6976a356bf1167cc834b06f4165984367b8ca69ef/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "571074f25fbd2d154dcf2b563af0a3fd42c1d5987c561f4fb23ba37c785a49d1",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/571074f25fbd2d154dcf2b563af0a3fd42c1d5987c561f4fb23ba37c785a49d1/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "816a19116f2d",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abcd1234!",
                "MYSQL_DATABASE=db",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.13-1debian8"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "Image": "mysql:5.7.13",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "99fb1d64dbd98500d7dddae88ea2b53e712da9a709f8541fcae413f52d18a309",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "4306"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/99fb1d64dbd9",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "375f5604e67cd5282d09585e2b211df7d8c1482b448f95003b38eaf5755c3982",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "526388f448225716c3159ae806600b8507086e898f41d3945d24d8c4572e3848",
                    "EndpointID": "375f5604e67cd5282d09585e2b211df7d8c1482b448f95003b38eaf5755c3982",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And `telnet`:

```sh
telnet 0.0.0.0 4306
Trying 0.0.0.0...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

```sh
telnet 172.17.0.1 4306
Trying 172.17.0.1...
Connected to 172.17.0.1.
```

By default the test uses `jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:4306/db`, but if I change this to `jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.1:4306/db` it's able to connect.

I tried using `postgres` instead of `mysql` and had the same problem.

My question is why it's unable to connect to `0.0.0.0`? Is it because it's a container in a container in a pod? I'm new to this technology.

Answer (score 1):

`0.0.0.0` is not even an [address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) , so I wouldn't expect that to work. It's typically used on servers/services to bind to `any` IP address (or meaning not applicable) but not by clients trying to connect to a server/service. If you are really connecting locally you could use `localhost` (DNS canonical) or just `127.0.0.1`. You didn't specify the connection string on your test but it could be that it's just connecting to the local socket `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` instead of the IP address (❓)

`172.17.0.1` is the local container address so that's always going to work as long as you expose the port, but the issue is that your container may not always have the same address depending on what's running on the specific machine where you are instantiating the container.

✌️

Comment: Locally it can connect to `0.0.0.0:4306` and `localhost:4306` but not `172.17.0.1:4306` in Jenkins it has the opposite behaviour.

Comment: It really depends on how your app or your MySQL client interprets `0.0.0.0` maybe it realizes that it needs to connect to the socket?

Comment: _"Locally it can connect to 0.0.0.0:4306"_ - really ??? I would really like to see your `telnet` result saying `Connected to 0.0.0.0`. :) `0.0.0.0` is typically used to denote all IPs, configured on all network interfaces on a local system. If your app is configured to listen on `0.0.0.0` it means it will bind to all those IP addresses. But I've never heard anyone trying to connect to `0.0.0.0`.